# Sequelize association arent incialized

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

hello im tryng to use include on a query on sequelize but it returns that the two tables are not related

model atestado
it contains atestado data and two FKs one from medicoModel and another one from pacienteModel

```
'use strict';
const config = require('../config/config');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DEV_DATABASE_URL, {
    dialect: 'postgres' // Adicione esta linha para especificar o dialeto
});
const medicoModel = require("./medicomodel")(sequelize, DataTypes);
const pacienteModel = require('./pacientemodel')(sequelize, DataTypes);

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const atestadoModel = sequelize.define('atestadoModel', {
    medicoFK: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      references:{
      model: medicoModel,
      key: 'rg'
    }
    },
    pacienteFK: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      references:{
      model: pacienteModel,
      key: 'rg'
    }
    },
    InativeAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    tableName: 'atestado',
    paranoid: true,
    deletedAt: 'InativeAt'
  });

  atestadoModel.associate = (models) => {
    atestadoModel.belongsTo(models.medicoModel, { foreignKey: 'medicoFK' });
    atestadoModel.belongsTo(models.pacienteModel, { foreignKey: 'pacienteFK' });
  };

  return atestadoModel;
};
```

model medico

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const medicoModel = sequelize.define('medicoModel', {
    rg: DataTypes.STRING,
    InativeAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    tableName: 'medico',
    paranoid: true,
    deletedAt: 'InativeAt'
  });

  medicoModel.associate = (models) => {
    medicoModel.hasMany(models.atestadoModel, { foreignKey: 'medicoFK' });
  };

  return medicoModel;
};
```

index

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.js')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

and the Controller

```
const config = require('../database/config/config');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DEV_DATABASE_URL, {
    dialect: 'postgres' // Adicione esta linha para especificar o dialeto
});
const medicoModel = require('../database/models/medicomodel')(sequelize, DataTypes);
const atestadoModel = require('../database/models/atestadomodel')(sequelize, DataTypes);
class AtestadoController {
    
    async show(req, res) {
        try {
            const atestado = await atestadoModel.findAll({
                include: [medicoModel]
            });
            res.status(200).json(atestado);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.status(404).json({ error: 'Ocorreu um erro ao buscar os atestados.' });
        }
    }
    
}

module.exports = new AtestadoController();
```

I tried to use include on a query on atestadomodel including medicomodel but i got this error:

EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Medico is not associated to Atestado!
at Atestado._getIncludedAssociation (/home/ficdev/GestaoAtestado/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:565:13)
at Atestado._validateIncludedElement (/home/ficdev/GestaoAtestado/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:502:53)
at /home/ficdev/GestaoAtestado/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:421:37
at Array.map ()
at Atestado._validateIncludedElements (/home/ficdev/GestaoAtestado/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:417:39)
at Atestado.findAll (/home/ficdev/GestaoAtestado/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1124:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async show (/home/ficdev/GestaoAtestado/src/app/controllers/atestadoControllerGestor.js:32:30)

Comment: I would make sure that those `hasMany()` calls are actually happening, also I've always set up "hasMany" in one direction and "hasOne" in the other just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use initialized models from `index` and don't import them once again directly (because that way you register them once again without any associations):

```js
const config = require('../database/config/config');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const { medicoModel, atestadoModel } = require('../database/models');

class AtestadoController {
    
    async show(req, res) {
        try {
            const atestado = await atestadoModel.findAll({
                include: [medicoModel]
            });
...
```